# TSQL: How to avoid cursors

Tags: t-sql, triggers, database-cursor

I've created a trigger on the table *Customer* that adds the email address 'PW@essef.be' to the table *eMail* when 'PW' is selected as representative (*CustomerRep*) in the table *Customer*.
The trigger works but, to make multi-row updates possible, I used a cursor. Now, I keep reading that cursors are a bad idea, so I'd like to convert the trigger below. How can I do this, please?

```
ALTER TRIGGER tUpdate_Customer ON Customer FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @CustomerID AS INT
    DECLARE cCustomer SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT CustomerID FROM INSERTED WHERE CustomerRep='PW'

    OPEN cCustomer
    FETCH FIRST FROM cCustomer INTO @CustomerID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    IF ISNULL((SELECT 'X' AS Found FROM eMail WHERE eMailCustomerID=@CustomerID AND eMail='PW@essef.be'), '-')<>'X'
      INSERT INTO eMail (eMailCustomerID, eMail) VALUES (@CustomerID, 'PW@essef.be')
        FETCH NEXT FROM cCustomer INTO @CustomerID
    END
  CLOSE cCustomer
  DEALLOCATE cCustomer
END
```

Comment: Use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` and `INSERT` ***all*** the rows you need in one go. You need to think in sets, not iteratively. What do you want to do to the data set, *not* what do I want to do to each row.

Comment: "What do you want to do to the data set, not what do I want to do to each row.": Great tip!

Answer (score 1):

Had a blind go there, but try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tUpdate_Customer ON Customer FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO eMail (eMailCustomerID, eMail)
        SELECT i.CustomerID,'PW@essef.be'
        FROM inserted as i
        WHERE 
            i.CustomerRep='PW'
            AND EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM eMail as e
                WHERE e.eMailCustomerID=i.CustomerID AND e.eMail='PW@essef.be'
            )
END
```

Comment: This did the trick (after changing _AND EXIST_ to _AND NOT EXISTS_)!
It's so obvious when you see it... 

Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Avoiding unneccessary cursors, that's good business.